How to approximate the gradient of $f(x)g(x)$ when $f(x)$ is non-differentiable but has a smooth approximate $h(x)$?
Consider optimizing $\sum_{t=1}^n f_t(x)g_t(x)$ using online gradient descent. However $f_t(x)$ is non-differentiable  and has a smooth approximate $h_t(x)$ . The online gradient descent is as follows:
$$x_{t+1}=x_t-\eta Grad(f_t(x_t)g_t(x_t))$$
Take $f_t(x)=\mathbf{1}(x>s_t)-\frac{1}{2},h_t(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-2(x-s_t)}}-\frac{1}{2},g_t(x)=s_t-x, s_t \sim Normal(1,0.5)$ as an example, I am confused which approximate gradient I should choose:
(1): $\text{Grad}(f_t(x)g_t(x)) \approx \bigg[\mathbf{1}(x>s_t)-\frac{1}{2}\bigg](-1)=f_t(x)g^{'}(x)$
(2): $\text{Grad}(f_t(x)g_t(x)) \approx \bigg[\frac{1}{1+e^{-2(x-s_t)}}-\frac{1}{2}\bigg](-1)=h_t(x) g_{t}^{'}(x)$
(3): $\text{Grad}(f_t(x)g_t(x)) \approx h_t^{'}(x)g_t(x)+f_t(x)g_{t}^{'}(x)$
(4): $\text{Grad}(f_t(x)g_t(x)) \approx h_t^{'}(x)g_t(x)+h_t(x)g_{t}^{'}(x)$
(1) (2) considers the derivative of $\mathbf{1}(x>s_t)$ as zero (like subgradient methods) while (3) and (4) uses the chain rule and $h_t(x)$ to approximate $f_t(x)$. Our experiments show that with different choices of $\eta$ only (1) and (3) work and (3) is better than (1). But intuitively I think we should choose (4). Is there any explanation for the result?

I cannot imagine why (4) would be intuitively better than (3). A use of $h$ is only an approximation to $f$. $h'$ is acting as your best pretense for what $f'$ ought to be. So (3) amounts to $f'g + fg'$. The first term is an approximation, while the second term is exact.  (4) differs by replacing the exact $fg'$ by the approximation $hg'$. Why you expect changing out the exact value for another approximation would be more accurate?

Because our goal is to minimize the non-differentiable loss function, I think it's more resonable to find an approximate smooth function and minimize it using gradient descent (like (4)). I am kind of confused with the difference between approximating the original function or directly approximating the gradient.

Exactly. Your goal is to minimize the loss function, not some approximation to it. Because it is non-differentiable, you have no choice but to estimate an approximate slope for it. That is what the first term in (3) and (4) does. But the second term in (3) deals with the actual loss function, while in (4) it is the approximation. If you are minimizing the loss function, not the approximation, which seems more appropriate to use?
